# Tensorflow: get variable or tensor by name in a nested scope

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have the following code which defines a nested `tf.variable_scope()`.

```
def function(inputs)
   with tf.variable_scope("1st") as scope:
     #define some variables here using tf.get_variable()
   with tf.variable_scope("2nd") as scope:
     #define some variables here using tf.get_variable()
     my_wanted_variable = tf.get_variable('my_wanted_variable',[dim0, 
                                             dim1], tf.float(32)，
                                         tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
```

In another class, I want to get `my_wanted_variable`, I use

```
with tf.variable_scope("function/2nd", reuse=True):
  got_my_wanted_variable = tf.get_variable("my_wanted_variable")
```

I was told that

> ValueError: Variable function/2nd/my_wanted_variable does not exist,
>   or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set
>   reuse=None in VarScope?

If I set `reuse=None` when fetching `my_wanted_variable` then,

> ValueError: Shape of a new variable (function/2nd/my_wanted_variable)
>   must be fully defined, but instead was .

So, how can I get a variable (or tensor) by name in a nested scope.

**add debug info**:
I used `print(xxx.name)` to see what is their name and scope indeed, I found that although their scope is right, e.g `xxx/function/2nd`. all variables which defined in scope `1st` and `2nd` are not named by their assigned name, for example, `my_wanted_variable` is `xxx/function/2nd/sub:0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:0` is normal for every variable (it symbolizes the endpoint). 
The name sub is not that weird it just shows that you did not name explicitely the variable so it gave the name of the operation you used (`tf.sub()` probably) to the tensor.

Use explicitely the argument called name="my_wanted_variable". Try without a scope first to be sure it is named appropriately. Then use print `nn.name` or inspect the nodes of the `graph_def` object to check.

Comment: Thanks, but why `tf.get_variable('my_wanted_variable',[dim0, dim1], tf.float(32)， tf.constant_initializer(0.0))` did not name it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Or we could check all the tensor in the debug mode with,

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model.ckpt-30000.meta')
    model.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

then, in debug mode,

```
graph._collections
```

This will enlist all the context_tensor, training_op, trainable_variables, variables.

or Even Better is:

```
[tensor.name for tensor in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```